# Animate Fill SVG on Hover Mode

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi guys I am trying to animate the FILL of my SVG.

What I want is that when I hovered my mouse the FILL will come out from the bottom to top filling in the whole circle. But I am stack how to apply the same using CSS3 transfrom: scale property.

[image]

As an example check out this demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/
That example is CSS not SVG I need to apply this pop-up FILL effect on my SVG.

here's my code so far:

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px"
     height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="icon">

<style type="text/css">     
    .st0
    {
        fill:none;
        stroke:#F2F2F2;
        stroke-width:4;
        stroke-miterlimit:10;
    }

    #icon .st0{
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
    }

    #icon:hover .st0{ 
        fill: #ffffff;
        stroke: #1f8a4c;
        cursor: pointer;
    }       
</style>


<g id="container">
    <circle class="st0" cx="101" cy="99" r="89.333"/>
</g>

<g id="icon-details">
    <path class="st0" d="M146.899,134.202c3.856,4.702,2.772,11.963-2.418,16.218l0,0c-5.192,4.258-12.523,3.896-16.38-0.806
        l-30.004-36.594c-3.855-4.701-2.772-11.964,2.418-16.22l0,0c5.19-4.256,12.523-3.895,16.377,0.808L146.899,134.202z"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="77.843" cy="72.434" r="33.331"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="77.844" cy="72.434" r="22.343"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Check out JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uhkwLuph/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with an interesting but working solution. We want to use `scale`, but out initial fill size should be 0 (scaling a 0-size element does nothing).

However, we know that a pixel is a pixel, and so a circle with as size of, let's say, 0.1 pixels will not render. Thus, we set the initial "fill" circle size to be small, then scale by a large factor:

```
<g id="fill-group" transform="translate(101, 99)">
    <circle class="fill" r="0.1" />
</g>
```

Also note here that we use a `transform` property on the group instead of setting `cx` and `cy` like on the other elements so that the circle scales with the correct origin.

Then the CSS would look like:

```
#icon .fill {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    fill: #ffffff;
}
#icon:hover .fill {
    -webkit-transform: scale(893, 893);
}
```

And here's a Fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/uhkwLuph/20/

Comment: @Anubhav Nice catch, that was only because my fill element wasn't part of the `st0` class. Changed it so the rule is now `#icon:hover { cursor: pointer; }` instead of `#icon:hover .st0 { cursor: pointer; }`. Updated the linked fiddle as well.